# Estructura con métodos estáticos y propiedades estáticas

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dev-c++

Consideren lo siguiente:

```
struct Foo
{
  static int x;

  static void SetValue()
  {
    Foo::x = 10;
  }

  static void ShowValue()
  {
    cout << Foo::x << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Foo::SetValue();
  Foo::ShowValue();
}
```

Esto mismo para mi gusto esta bien, pero no logró que compile, me retorna el siguiente error DEV-C++ con GCC 4.9.2:

```
C:\$DIR\main.o  main.cpp:(.text$_ZN3Foo8SetValueEv[__ZN3Foo8SetValueEv]+0x5): undefined reference to `Foo::x'
```

o si intento compilarlo en visual studio 2013:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: símbolo externo "public: static int Foo::x"
>   (?x@Foo@@2HA) sin resolver    C:\Users\Niko\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Testing A\Testing A\main.obj    Testing A

En la publicación anterior un hombre me respondió con un compilador online que lo compilo sin problemas:
[Ex](https://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-Wall+-Wextra',source:'%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Astruct+Foo%0A%7B%0A++static+int+x%3B%0A%0A++static+void+SetValue()%0A++%7B%0A++++Foo::x+%3D+10%3B%0A++%7D%0A%0A++static+void+ShowValue()%0A++%7B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+Foo::x+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++Foo::SetValue()%3B%0A++Foo::ShowValue()%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

y resulto ser el mismo código.

Comment: Creo que es por el tema de que para usar una estructura debe estar previamente definida ,y como referencias a X dentro de Foo usando Foo:X , el compilador no sabe quien es Foo ,pues se entra a una especie de bucle , vi algo parecido en java , y por eso te lo digo.

Comment: Si, he pensado en ello al respecto, pero como haría para referirme a la misma propiedad de la misma estructura ya que allí no podría usar this por la razón de que esta es static.

Comment: ESto te puede ayudar.
http://ideone.com/E9v4iG
Al parecer es porque solo declaras la variable x , pero no defines tu variable estatica,para poder hacer Foo::x , lo que esta implicito dentro de las funciones estaticas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te has topado con uno de los errores más confusos de C++. Lo que el error de enlazado te está diciendo es que ha encontrado la **declaración** de la variable pero no su **definición**; es parecido a cuando defines una función pero no le das cuerpo o cuando declaras una variable `extern` pero no existe ninguna versión no `extern` de la misma para usar como definición.

Dado que la variable es estática, debe existir [una y sólo una](https://unoyunodiez.com/?s=unidad+de+traducci%C3%B3n) definición de la misma en algún lugar del código, para ello intenta lo siguiente:

```
struct Foo
{
  static int x; // Declaracion.

  static void SetValue()
  {
    Foo::x = 10;
  }

  static void ShowValue()
  {
    cout << Foo::x << endl;
  }
}

int Foo::x; // Definicion (notese la ausencia de static)
```

Pero ¡alerta! si la definición está en un archivo de cabecera (`*.hpp`), y este archivo de cabecera se incluye en más de una [unidad de traducción](http://www.genbetadev.com/cc/estructura-del-codigo-fuente-en-c) (ver apartado *Duplicado de definiciones* del enlace), podrías acabar con múltiples definiciones de `Foo::x` y el enlazador no sabrá cuál de ellas es la correcta y mostrará otro error de enlazado; para evitar esto deberás definir la variable en un archivo de código (`*.cpp`).

---

#### Editado

---

> Igual yo mismo saqué esta técnica o lógica de PHP, 3v4l.org/7lFqr pero cada lenguaje tiene su tema. gracias por la respuesta

Efectivamente, cada lenguaje es diferente. Pese a que tanto [PHP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) como C++ han sido influenciados por C, cada uno de ellos trabaja de manera distinta.

Por ejemplo, no puede usarse `static` para miembros de `struct` en C y pese a que lo único que se de PHP es que su [manual está escrito en una servilleta](http://james-iry.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html) es evidente que su uso de `static` es diferente al de C y C++.

La parte relevante del [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) sobre los miembros estáticos de objetos es la sección § 9.4.2 que paso a traducir (el resaltado es mío, no del documento original):

> #### 9.4.2 Datos miembro estáticos
>
> 1. **Un dato miembro `static` no es parte del sub-objeto o la clase**. Si un dato miembro estático es declarado `thread_local` existirá una copia por cada hilo. **Si un dato miembro estático no es declarado `thread_local` existirá una copia del dato que será compartida por todos los objetos de la clase**.
> 2. **La declaración de un dato miembro `static` en su definición de clase no es una definición y puede ser un tipo incompleto** diferente de `void` cualificado constante o volátil. **La definición para un dato miembro estático debe aparecer en el contexto del espacio de nombres en que se definió la clase que contiene dicho miembro**. En la definición en el contexto de espacio de nombres, el nombre del dato miembro estático debe ser cualificado con el nombre de su clase usando el operador `::`. La expresión de *inicialización* del dato miembro estático está en el contexto de su clase [*Ejemplo*:
>
>    ```
>    class process {
>        static process* run_chain;
>        static process* running;
>    };
>    process* process::running = get_main();
>    process* process::run_chain = running;
>    ```
>
>    El dato miembro estático `run_chan` de la clase `process` está definido en el contexto global; la notación `process::run_chain` especifica que el miembro `run_chain` pertenece a la clase `process` y al contexto de la clase `process`. En la definición del dato estático, la expresión de inicialización se refiere al dato miembro estático en el proceso en ejecución. -*fin del ejemplo*]

Comment: Igual yo mismo saqué esta técnica o lógica de PHP, https://3v4l.org/7lFqr pero cada lenguaje tiene su tema. gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: si te das cuenta ahi sale error de linkeado osea no hay error al ensamblar sino al linkear